# modify google chrome extension to remove tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to modify an existing extension (readability) for Chrome. Right now when you save a page with readability it does not close the tab afterwards.

The code in the extension calls a script hosted on their server:

```
(function(){
    rdb.chrome.inject_page_script('/bookmarklet/save.js');
 }());
```

I changed the code to look like this:

```
(function(){
    rdb.chrome.inject_page_script('/bookmarklet/save.js');
    chrome.tabs.getSelected( null, function(tab) 
        { chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);   return true; }); 
 }());
```

But it doesn't close the tab or use their function properly. I tried my close tab code alone in the function without their call and it didn't close the tab.

Is there a way to modify their call to close the tab after it does their script to bookmark the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use chrom`chrome.tabs.getSelected` anymore as it has recently been deprecated. It's  recommend that you use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab) instead. However, it's also worth mentioning that both of these methods [require the tabs permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#manifest).

Without looking at the readability extension myself it's hard to determine why your code wasn't being called but I suggest you add debug (e.g. `console.log('foo')`) statements to the code in order to determine why that code isn't being reached.

Finally, ensure you are following the [correct debugging/development procedures](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_debugging/) so that you can test your changes easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function(){});
});
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined"